# Stored Procedure MVC3 error on execution

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

I got a stored procedure that reads a table and insert those data to antoher table. That's the way how it works because the first table imports data from excel using a package with SSIS.

In EF4 I imported the SP and create function import:
This SP has 2 IN variables and 2 OUT varibales.

The IN varibales are parameters and OUT variables are a message and the number of records created.

I put the code generated:

```
#Region "Function Imports"

''' <summary>
''' No Metadata Documentation available.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="parIDPoliza">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
''' <param name="parFechaActual">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
''' <param name="varError">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
''' <param name="varKontador">No Metadata Documentation available.</param>
Public Function spCargaArchivos(parIDPoliza As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int64), parFechaActual As Nullable(Of Global.System.DateTime), varError As ObjectParameter, varKontador As ObjectParameter) As Integer
    Dim parIDPolizaParameter As ObjectParameter
    If (parIDPoliza.HasValue) Then
        parIDPolizaParameter = New ObjectParameter("parIDPoliza", parIDPoliza)
    Else
        parIDPolizaParameter = New ObjectParameter("parIDPoliza", GetType(Global.System.Int64))
    End If

    Dim parFechaActualParameter As ObjectParameter
    If (parFechaActual.HasValue) Then
        parFechaActualParameter = New ObjectParameter("parFechaActual", parFechaActual)
    Else
        parFechaActualParameter = New ObjectParameter("parFechaActual", GetType(Global.System.DateTime))
    End If

    Return MyBase.ExecuteFunction("spCargaArchivos", parIDPolizaParameter, parFechaActualParameter, varError, varKontador)

End Function

#End Region
```

But when I try to execute the SP I get error:
**The parameter at index 2 in the parameters array is null**

**Execution**

```
Dim varMensaje As Objects.ObjectParameter = Nothing
Dim varError As Objects.ObjectParameter = Nothing
Dim varRespuesta As Integer = varEntidades.spCargaArchivos(parIDPoliza, Now.Date, varError, varMensaje)
```

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve this.... after two hard days.
I don't know if it's a bug or not but the error is how to send OUTPUT variables.

The types are the same that Function Import in Model Browser properties

```
Dim varTotalRegistros As Objects.ObjectParameter = New Objects.ObjectParameter("varKontador", GetType(Global.System.Int64))
Dim varError As Objects.ObjectParameter = New Objects.ObjectParameter("varError", GetType(Global.System.String))
Dim varRespuesta As Integer = varEntidades.spCargaArchivos(parIDPoliza, Now.Date, varError, varTotalRegistros)
```

Good luck!!